# Converting from CStringArray* to C++/CLI Array

Tags: c++-cli

Could you please let me know how to convert CStringArray* to C++/CLI array. I am creating a wrapper dll which needs my data to be converted to unmanaged code. I am able to use basic data types like double * but not for CStringArray *.

Thank you.

Comment: Allocate an `Array<String^>` based on the `CStringArray` length, then for each element in the `CStringArray`, marshal as a `String^` and add to the array...?

Comment: @crashmstr Yes, I allocated the memory for the Array - "gcnew array<String ^>" but I am not sure how to marshal it

Comment: `marshal_as<String^>(my_cstring)` - [Overview of Marshalling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was referring to the [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6(v=vs.110).aspx) and got confused. I will try to mark the answer. Sorry i am really bad in formatting the comment.

Comment: @crashmstr I am getting this error if i try to marshal "error C4996:'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,_From_Type>::marshal_as': This conversion is not supported by the library". I am following the link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384859(v=vs.100).aspx.

Comment: Why don't you add the code you have to the question? Otherwise, I don't know what might be wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61288/discussion-between-rag-and-crashmstr).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
#include <msclr/marshal.h>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
#include <msclr/marshal_atl.h>


CStringArray * myData; //Assume data is already filled
array<String ^> unmanagedData = gcnew array<String ^) (m_nDataCount);

for (int j = 0; j < m_nDataCount; j++)
{
    String ^ stepName = marshal_as<String ^> (myData->GetAt(j));
    unmanagedData[j] = stepName;
}
```

Marshaling as is the solution. Thanks to @crashmstr for helping me to crack this